# New SharePoint files always open in Word Online

Tags: word, file, site-settings

My workplace has a SharePoint library that we use to track product changes.  We would prefer that when users create a new document that it opens in the Word client application immediately rather than in Word Online.  I cannot find any information about where the setting is buried to get this functionality

The reason we want it this way is that we only have to save the file under one name initially in order to keep the library decluttered.  When the online application is used and someone forgets to rename the document we end up with a bunch of Document##.docx files.

Answer (score 1):

In the Library in question, go to "Library Settings" then "Advanced Settings" in there you should see the option to open in browser, i.e. Word Online, or open in client application, i.e. Word Client application.

Comment: I changed that setting, but new documents still open in the online editor, and I then have to click "edit in Word" in order to open the client app.